# how to remove ALKCO flourescent L40 bulb

Tags: lighting

I've got ALKCO "Lincandescent" flourescents in the master bath in a house built 8 years ago.  They apparently discontinued the fixture around the same time.  One bulb has burned out, **I can't figure out how to remove it**, and the mfr can't help.  Here's the product:
https://rexel-cdn.com/Products/84825A51-8E8A-441A-B16B-8D0CB23D2E6F/84825A51-8E8A-441A-B16B-8D0CB23D2E6F.pdf
Most flourescent tubes have pins on the ends and you twist out the bulb.  But these tubes don't have end-pins.  The tubes apparently look like this:
https://www.rexelusa.com/usr/Root-Category/Lamps%2C-Bulbs%2C-Ballasts/Bulbs---Incandescent/Incandescent---Tubular/Lamps---T10/Alkco-L40-Incandescent-Lamp%2C-T10%2C-40%22%2C-150W/p/206983
Any advice on how to remove it?  Thanks!
.
.
Thanks for the great advice.  Yes, it IS an incandescent, even though it's a long tube and has what looks like a ballast.  And quite right, when I pulled it straight out, very very firmly, it did come out, without breaking.  I replaced it with an LED, which is brighter and a bit harsher.  Now I need to decide if that's OK, or if I'll look for one that matches the brightness and color of the other three.
Thanks to all for the accurate advice and guidance.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm not sure how we could figure this out remotely if you can't figure it out in person. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: This *isn't a fluorescent*. Read the docs.  It's a genuine, bona fide, actual **incandescent bulb** with a glowing filament, just of a super custom package design. This is in the Edison camp, not the Tesla camp.   So you are married to a single supplier.  The upside is, it's a Tier 1 supplier who will probably answer the phone (if we're no help).

Comment: I would wrap the bulb with a towel and pull harder if it breaks the towel will protect your hands. I have never seen one of that style bulbs , if they no longer make them damage to the fixture would not be a big deal as it will need to be replaced anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The bulbs pull straight out, there are spring clips on the back sides at each end making the connections. If you grab the bulb at the ends and pull straight out from the fixture, it will come out. Sometimes, because these were often used as vanity lights in bathrooms, the spring clips and connectors on the bulb will corrode, making it tough to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF you posted shows screw slot mounting on the back of the fixture. Are you able to shove the fixture about half an inch in one direction parallel to its long axis?  It might pop off the wall or whatever it's mounted to when you do that.